# Failed to compile. Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have been googling about this error and found so many suggestions and solutions but none of them works for my case.

I'm running my app with node

After `npm start` it shows me:

Failed to compile.

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './componentes/Topo' in 'C:\Users\filip\Documents\Filipe\1 - Front-End\React\missao-front-end-loja-de-oculos\src'
> ERROR in ./src/App.js 4:0-38
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './componentes/Topo' in 'C:\Users\filip\Documents\Filipe\1 - Front-End\React\missao-front-end-loja-de-oculos\src'

[structure of my code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgfue.png) C:\Users\filip\Documents\Filipe\1 - Front-End\React\missao-front-end-loja-de-oculos

index.html from ./public

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>Óticas vida - Loja de óculos</title>

</html>
```

App.js

```
import Topo from './componentes/Topo';
import Conteudo from './componentes/Conteudo';
import Rodape from './componentes/Rodape/';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Topo />
      <Conteudo />
      <Rodape />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js from ./componentes/conteudo

```
import SecaoCapa from '../componentes/SecaoCapa';
import SecaoSobre from '../componentes/SecaoSobre';
import SecaoProdutos from '../SecaoProdutos';
import SecaoContato from '../SecaoContato';

export default function Conteudo() {
  return (
    <main>
      <SecaoCapa />
      <SecaoProdutos />
      <SecaoSobre />
      <SecaoContato />
    </main>
  )
}
```

Topo from .componentes/Topo

```
export default function Topo() {
  return (
    <header>
        <div>
          <img src='public\assets\logo.png' alt='imagem de um óculos à direita e o nome da ótica à esquerda' />

          <nav>
            <a href='#produtos'>PRODUTOS</a>
            <a href='#sobre'>SOBRE</a>
            <a href='#contato'>CONTATO</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
  )
}
```

I tried yarn but:

> yarn : The file C:\Users\filip\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.ps1 cannot be loaded because the script execution was
> disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
> On line:1 character:1

- yarn

  - CategoryInfo : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

I already deleted package-lock.json, but nothing has changed. Tried `npm cache clean --force` then
`npm install` but no result.

I'm considering the possibility to be a path issue but didn't find then yet.

I aware that I am a newbie and I need some guidance from the masters here.

Any idea how could this being fixed?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you edit your code into the question as text, instead of using screenshots? This will make it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: Also, could you share the contents of the file `componentes/Topo/Topo.js`?

Comment: Made it. And please let me know if I need to improve anything, whatever it is, with my code itself or here in the way I'm sharing things. thx

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide the content of the Topo.js my guess is that you are not exporting well the component Topo that's why react throws an error while trying to import it

Comment: Yep. I'm thinking the same thing, but I'm not understanding where the error is. I edited the original post and included code instead of just images. Still here trying to figure it out. thx